# Why does my custom xkb layout not recognize the level switches?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm using a custom layout that is basically a heavily modified variant of the German PUQ layout that I initially just wrote over the AdNW layout, and to keep it from being overwritten by updates I now configured it as a custom layout. However, unlike the modified AdNW-layout, this one doesn't recognize the level switch settings when I load it in Gnome, even though I just copypasted it and changed the names. Why is that and how can I change it? For reference, here is the layout:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "custom_base" {
    include "de(neo_base)"

    key.type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL_LEVEL_FIVE_LOCK";
    key <AD04> { [ comma,                    enfilledcircbullet,     NoSymbol,                U03D1,                   NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U2203,                   NoSymbol              ] };
    key <AB04> { [ period,                   endash,                 NoSymbol,                U03F1,                   NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U2261,                   NoSymbol              ] };

    key.type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC_LEVEL_FIVE_LOCK";
    key <AD01> { [ p,                       P,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_pi,            NoSymbol,          Greek_PI,                multiply,                U043F                 ] };
    key <AD02> { [ u,                       U,                       NoSymbol,                NoSymbol,                NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U2200,                   U0443                 ] };
    key <AD03> { [ udiaeresis,              Udiaeresis,              NoSymbol,                Greek_chi,               NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U2191,                   U044B                 ] };
    key <AD05> { [ q,               Q,               NoSymbol,                NoSymbol,                NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U22C9,                   U044C                 ] };
    key <AD06> { [ v,                       V,                       NoSymbol,                NoSymbol,                NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U22CA,                   U0432                 ] };
    key <AD07> { [ c,                       C,                       NoSymbol,                NoSymbol,                4,                 NoSymbol,                U227A,           U0447                 ] };
    key <AD08> { [ l,                       L,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_lambda,            5,             Greek_LAMBDA,                U2227,                   U043B                 ] };
    key <AD09> { [ m,                       M,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_mu,                6,             NoSymbol,                U227B,           U043C                 ] };
    key <AD10> { [ f,                       F,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_phi,               NoSymbol,              Greek_PHI,                U220F,           U0444                 ] };
    key <AD11> { [ adiaeresis,              Adiaeresis,              NoSymbol,                NoSymbol,                NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U2210,                   U044A                 ] };
    key <AC01> { [ h,                       H,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_eta,               NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U2194,           U0445                 ] };
    key <AC02> { [ i,                       I,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_iota,              NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U2190,           U0438                 ] };
    key <AC03> { [ e,                       E,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_epsilon,           NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U2193,                   U044D                 ] };
    key <AC04> { [ a,                       A,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_alpha,             NoSymbol,              U2135,                U2192,                   U044F                 ] };
    key <AC05> { [ o,                       O,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_omicron,           NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U21A6,           U043E                 ] };
    key <AC06> { [ d,                       D,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_delta,             NoSymbol,              Greek_DELTA,                partialderivative,       U0434                 ] };
    key <AC07> { [ t,                       T,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_tau,               1,                     NoSymbol,                U003C,           U0442                 ] };
    key <AC08> { [ r,                       R,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_rho,               2,             NoSymbol,                U2228,                   U0440                 ] };
    key <AC09> { [ n,                       N,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_nu,                3,             NoSymbol,                U003E,                   U043D                 ] };
    key <AC10> { [ s,                       S,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_sigma,             NoSymbol,              Greek_SIGMA,                U221E,            U0441                ] };
    key <AC11> { [ ssharp,                  U1E9E,                   NoSymbol,                Greek_finalsmallsigma,   NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                jot,                     NoSymbol              ] };
    key <AB01> { [ k,                       K,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_kappa,             NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U2211,           U043A                 ] };
    key <AB02> { [ y,                       Y,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_upsilon,           NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U222B,                   U044E                 ] };
    key <AB03> { [ x,                       X,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_xi,                NoSymbol,              Greek_XI,                U2205,                   NoSymbol              ] };
    key <AB05> { [ odiaeresis,              Odiaeresis,              NoSymbol,                Greek_psi,               NoSymbol,              Greek_PSI,                U221D,           U0446                 ] };
    key <AB06> { [ j,                       J,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_theta,              0,                Greek_THETA,                U221E,                   U0437                 ] };
    key <AB07> { [ g,                       G,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_gamma,             7,             Greek_GAMMA,                radical,                 U0433                 ] };
    key <AB08> { [ z,                       Z,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_zeta,              8,                 NoSymbol,                U2225,                   U0436                 ] };
    key <AB09> { [ w,                       W,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_omega,             9,             Greek_OMEGA,                U2223,           U0437                 ] };
    key <AB10> { [ b,                       B,                       NoSymbol,                Greek_beta,              NoSymbol,              U05D1,                U222B,           U0431                 ] };

      key <LSGT> { [ ssharp,                  U1E9E,                 NoSymbol,                Greek_finalsmallsigma,   NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U2208,                   U0448                 ] };  
      key <BKSL> { [     at,                  U1E9E,                 NoSymbol,                Greek_finalsmallsigma,   NoSymbol,              NoSymbol,                U22C8,                   U0449                 ] };
};

partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "custom" {

    include "custom(custom_base)"

    name[Group1]= "Custom";

    include "shift(both_capslock)"
    include "level3(caps_switch)"
    include "level3(ac11_switch)"
    include "level5(ralt_switch_lock)"
};
```

Edit: The output of `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` is

```
Setting verbose level to 10
WARNING: Running setxkbmap against an XWayland server
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Edit: after running `setxkbmap -layout custom`, the output of `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` is

```
Setting verbose level to 10
WARNING: Running setxkbmap against an XWayland server
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     custom
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+custom+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+custom+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
```

Note that this seems completely independent of the keymap I'm actually using, which is chosen by Gnome.

Edit3: It seems that wayland was overriding the `setxkbmap` settings. Under X11 I can set my layout using `setxkbmap`, but the problem persists. The output of `setxkbmap -layout custom` is slightly different though:

```
[alex@alex ~]$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     custom,us
variant:    ,
options:    lv3:ralt_switch,compose:menu
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+custom+us:2+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch)+compose(menu)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+custom+us:2+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch)+compose(menu)"  };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Comment: which directory do you put your file in? Is it in the same directory where included files are?

Comment: @Andra I put it into `\usr\share\X11\xkb\symbols` as per this guide: http://who-t.blogspot.com/2021/02/a-pre-supplied-custom-keyboard-layout.html

Comment: what's the output of `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` in terminal?

Comment: @Andra I added the output to my question.

Comment: why the layout `us`? I thought it should be `de` with variant "custom" or smth like that.

Comment: @Andra I find it strange too, but I get the same output when I use the modified AdNW-layout. I choose my layout using gnome, so I thought maybe it overrides the layout provided by X11.

Comment: @Andra I've now run `setxkbmap -layout custom` and again `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` and posted the output through second edit.

Comment: btw if you login X11, is it the same?

Comment: @Andra The problem persists, but the output of `setxkbmap -layout custom` changes, see above.

Comment: take a look at the correct syntax:  in the text pasted in your question there is no closing quote at the end of `include "de(neo_base)`, and `xkb_symbols "custom_base" {`doesn't have a closing bracket {.

Comment: @Andra Ah, sorry, I had corrected the lacking closing quote shortly after posting the question and thought I had updated the text to reflect that. I don't see the what bracket is missing though: there is no opening bracket after `xkb_symbols "custom_base"`, so no closing bracket is required, apart from the one closing the `xkb_symbols "custom" {"` bracket. This is exactly as it is with the modified adnw layout.

Comment: there is an opening bracket in `xkb_symbols "custom_base" {`, the closing should be before `partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys keypad_keys`, after describing of `key <BKSL>`. Not just `}`, but `};`.

Comment: @Andra Oh, sorry, I corrected that along with the missing quotes and forgot about it. The problem persists though. Again, sorry, I've been really tired these last two days.

Comment: I don't know what is (in which file) AdNW-layout, but why didn't you add your layout to `de` and make it as `variant`?  That is, why is it `layout` and not `variant` of --? I wanted to try your layout (as layout) but it was too strange.

Comment: @Andra When I started I didn't want to mess something up, so I just modified the adnw-layout in `de` and thought it worked well enough as a kludge. At some point, an update overwrote the entire `de`-file and I learned that they do that sometimes, so I made copies that I replaced the file with when that happened. Now I wanted to make a proper custom layout so I don't have to do that anymore. I can't say for sure, but I think if I just put it into the `de`-file, it would get overwritten as well. It must seem strange, but it is written to synergize with `dual-function-keys`, emacs and latex ^^.

Comment: the line `include "custom_base"` - if it copies the adnw , it should be `include "custom(custom_base)"` (if `custom` is the name of the layout file), shouldn't it?

Comment: @Andra That would make sense, so I tried it out, but the problem still persists.

Comment: have you tried without the line `include "level3(ac11_switch)"`? maybe it's not understandable.

Comment: @Andra Still doesn't work. It would have been surprising, since the same line works in the modified adnw-layout (`ac11_switch` is an entry in `level3` I wrote myself).

Comment: maybe one more strange thing: in the last `setxkbmap -print..` output there is the `symbols` line `pc+custom+us:2+inet(evdev)+level3(ralt_switch)+compose(menu)`, which actually uses `ralt_switch` two times (the first being in `custom` include). Try without this option: either remove it using GUI ("Keyboard Layout Options" in my current system) or `setxkbmap -option`.

Comment: @Andra I can remove the occurrence of `ralt_switch` in the `symbols` string through the GUI, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: so I tried again adding your layout: file /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/custom, commented out `//include "level3(ac11_switch)"` (because I don't have it), added a new `<layout>` in /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data`, choose your layout in Keyboard GUI. For seven on the top line I can get 7 € ¥. That is, if I switch **numlock off**. So `caps` and `ralt` are working for me.

Comment: @Andra I didn't configure `evdev.xml` because the guide said there was already an entry in it, and there is:

`    <layout>` 
`      <configItem>` 
 `<name>custom</name>` 
        `<shortDescription>custom</shortDescription>` 
`        <description>A user-defined custom Layout</description>` 
`      </configItem>` 
`      <variantList/>` 
`    </layout>`


Is there anything I should add to that? (It doesn't seem to format code snippets with paragraphs right in the comments).

Comment: If you can choose the layout in GUI, then it's ok..I would think. Anyway, I added it like in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/483026/782725. And did you run `reconfigure`? And what about numlock - it was why it seemed strange for me the first time. Can you get normal letters and numbers? For example, with the key F can you can get `a` and `A` but not `}`?

Comment: @Andra I did not run `dpkg-reconfigure`, since I'm on Arch, not a Debian-based system. But I tried logging out and in, that should suffice, right? I can write normal letters and numbers and even signs from the upper levels, but only using the default switches, not the ones I've configured.

Comment: tried with Manjaro live usb (not the latest) on the same computer: ralt is not working in your layout but it is not working in German Neo2 either

Comment: @Andra Do the other switches work? For instance, if you hold CapsLock, does it switch to the third level?

Comment: I'm back to my ubuntu-based system. Now I can't understand why I get ¥ with ralt+7 in your custom layout, it's the 3 el. in the definition (neo_base). If I choose "German Neo2" in GUI, both lsgt and ralt (btw I have a laptop with German keyboard) change nothing. If I set it with `setxkbmap -layout "de" -variant "neo" -option "lv5:ralt_switch_lock"`, it seems it works as intended, for example, with German "Z" I get kK!κ¡ (z, shift+z, caps+z, shift+caps+z, ralt+z). To set back previous config I use `setxkbmap -layout "lv,meg,custom,de" -variant "my,,,neo" -option`. But with your layout I'm lost.

Comment: @Andra Well, it shouldn't work like that. You should get ¥ if you press CapsLock+7 or AC11 (ä key)+7. Ralt+7 should give →. I'm assuming that, since the switches aren't loaded correctly, it defaults to using ralt as a level3-switch. If you'd try it as a variant of a German layout, like I do with adnw, you'd probably see that the switches work as intended (if you remove the AC11 switch).

Comment: I tried to google about not working 5th level switch and https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=102189 gave me the idea: if there are no key selected in options for 5th level (in GUI, but I suppose it would be the same with setxkbmap), Neo2 `ralt` does nothing, however, if there is a 5th level key (I chose lwin), then both `lsgt` and `ralt` start to work. So it may a bug. Still your question is not about Neo2. With your layout I cannot get caps for 3rd level nor ralt for 5th level. If I try it as a German variant, caps work as 3rd level switch and the 5th level like in the case of Neo2.

Comment: @Andra Yeah, I guess it's a bug. At this point I guess it's best I just notify them and ask them directly. Anyway, thanks for all the help! Also, I've put up my configuration files for xkb, dual-function-keys and Emacs on Github as part of a larger project, you can look at the dual-function-keys configuration if you like, I think it's actually fairly useful: https://github.com/nameiwillforget/Configfiles